# How do I go about this question on Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: Suppose that some matrix A can be represented as A = Tdiag(λ<sub>1</sub>,...,λ<sub>n</sub>)T<sup>-1</sup>. Show that A<sup>n</sup> = Tdiag(λ<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup>,...,λ<sub>n</sub><sup>n</sup>)T<sup>-1</sup>.

My try: We could rewrite A = Tdiag(λ<sub>1</sub>,...,λ<sub>n</sub>)T<sup>-1</sup> as A = TT<sup>-1</sup>diag(λ<sub>1</sub>,...,λ<sub>n</sub>). Then, using the identity matrix property, we get A = Idiag(λ<sub>1</sub>,...,λ<sub>n</sub>) = diag(λ<sub>1</sub>,...,λ<sub>n</sub>). Now we could just take both sides of the equation to the power n and get A<sup>n</sup> = Tdiag(λ<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup>,...,λ<sub>n</sub><sup>n</sup>)T<sup>-1</sup>. Hence proved.

Is this correct? If not, what would be the correct proof? Thanks :)

Comment: Try $A^{2} = A A$ and look for the identity matrix to simplify the right-hand side.

Comment: May I know where did I go wrong in my above proof? :) Can't I just get the identity matrix straight away by shifting the inverse of T right next to T?

Comment: No, because $T$ doesn't necessarily commute with a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $D= diag(\lambda_1,..., \lambda_n)$

You wrote: $TDT^{-1}=TT^{-1}D=D.$  In general this is wrong , since in general $T$ and $D$ do not commute.

We have $A^2 =TDT^{-1}TDT^{-1}=TD^2T.$

Now proceed by induction.-

Comment: Thanks. So when you say "proceed by induction", should I just complete the proof by writing this one line that "Since it holds for A^2, by induction we can also see that it holds for A^n"?